# Apache 2.4 .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

So I'm attempting to configure a server with Apache 2.4. I've got most things working, except for the .htaccess file. I've read through a couple posts/guides and I'm almost certain that my config is correct.

I've got rewrite_module enabled in my `http.conf`

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
```

In my `VirtualHost` I have the following directory directive.

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And this is my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js|\.js.map)$

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have a feeling that the `.htaccess` formatting for rewrites might have changed in 2.4, but I can't seem to find any decent examples saying how it should be looking. Is what I have still valid and if not, how should I go about changing it?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `RewriteRule . index.php` should be `RewriteRule .* index.php`? Or do you really want to match _only_ "any _single_ character?" See Apache 2.4 documentation for [Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex) for more guidance.

Comment: @Colt I've tried various different ways, nothing seems to work. At this point, I'm not even sure that the .htaccess is even being referenced/read.

Comment: what directory is the `.htaccess` file in?

Comment: it's located in /var/www/mysite/web

Comment: try moving `<Directory "/var/www/mysite/web">AllowOverride All</Directory>` to the `apache2.conf` file _above_ and `Include` directives

Comment: So move the directory for the VirtualHost out of the VirtualHost?

Comment: No, just the one directive. It really should not matter, but the AllowOverride directive is what enables .htaccess to have effect. It is often set outside of the vHost configuration to separate control

Comment: That didn't seem to make much of a difference :(

Comment: "formatting for rewrites might have changed in 2.4" - nothing changed with regards to these directives between Apache 2.2 and 2.4. Unfortunately, without knowing specifically _what_ is "not working", this question is near impossible to answer. You may also need to show your entire `VirtualHost`. What happens? Do you get any errors? Is `.htaccess` being processed at all? Why use `.htaccess` when you have access to the server config/VirtualHost? (If the "formatting/syntax" had changed you would probably get a 500 error.)